# How to set the position of one element relative to parents while implementing z-index?

Tags: html, css, z-index

http://jsfiddle.net/w697k849/

This is a simple demo. I want the yellow and red squares in the middle of black and red is on the top of yellow.

The conflict is if I use z-index to make red up to yellow I need to set position as absolute in CSS. But how can I control the position of red and yellow squares (making them dynamic)?

I want the position of all squares to be dynamic when I am resizing my page. So how to use z-index in this case?

```
<div id = 'all' style="position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background:black;
        display: block;
        /*text-align: center;*/">

    <div id = 'highscore' style="    z-index: 1;
    left: 10%;
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    ">

    </div>
        <canvas width="550" height="700" id="canvas" style="position: absolute;background:yellow;width: 200px;
    height: 200px;z-index:1;"></canvas>
    </div>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/w697k849/14/

Answer (score 0):

Try this; http://jsfiddle.net/w697k849/3/

```
<div id = 'all' style="position: relative;
width: 400px;
height: 400px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
background:black;
    display: block;
    /*text-align: center;*/">

<div id = 'highscore' style="    z-index: 1;
left: 40%;
background: red;
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
top: 50px;
">

</div>
    <canvas width="550" height="700" id="canvas" style="position: 
relative;background:yellow;width: 200px; top: 100px;
height: 200px;z-index:1;"></canvas>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Look this:

html:

```
<div id = 'all' style="">
    <div id = 'highscore' style=""></div>
    <canvas width="550" height="700" id="canvas" style=""></canvas>
</div>
```

css:

```
#all {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 400px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    background:black;
    display: block;
}
#highscore {
    z-index: 2;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 150px;
    background: red;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#canvas {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background:yellow;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    z-index:1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vrq9xtaL/

Answer (score 0):

CSS position and z-index rules apply for centralized divs and used width and height in % for resizing, note parent div has to specify height as not fixed as width so in my case I have added one more div at the parent level.

```css
#parent {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

#all {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  background: black;
  position: relative;
}

#highscore {
  width: 25%;
  /* convert fix size 100px into percentage for resizing */
  height: 25%;
  /* convert fix size 100px into percentage for resizing */
  background: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 36%;
  /*  (150px/400px)% calculate top position from parent height and child div position */
  left: 36%;
  /* same as left */
  z-index: 2;
}

#canvas {
  width: 50%;
  /* convert fix size 200px into percentage for resizing */
  height: 50%;
  /* convert fix size 200px into percentage for resizing */
  position: absolute;
  top: 25%;
  /*  (100px/400px)% calculate top position */
  left: 25%;
  background: yellow;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="all">
    <div id="highscore"></div>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  </div>
</div>
```